# Aligning equations in a way that && doesn't send the given line to the right

Tags: align

As an example:

```
\begin{align*}
2+x&=&3\\
&a&\\
&&b
\end{align*}
```

I would like the first line to be displayed as normal, but with $a$ underneath it aligned with the =, and the b aligned with the 3.

How can I edit my code so this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with the `alignat` environment, and the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    2+x& \eqmakebox[B]{${}={}$} &3\\
    & \eqmakebox[B]{$a$} \\
    & & b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not  clear to me why 3 `&`s are needed.  wouldn't two siffice?

Comment: @barbara beeton: You're right, as there is here not real need for a second alignment  point. It's an old habit I have to use $2k-1$ `&` for $k$ alignment groups.